# Weighted count of distinct items based on their frequency in a list

Tags: outliers

I have a list of items. Each item has some properties associated with them. For example, let's consider country. Let's say out of 100 entries, 98 are from US and 2 are from UK. When considering the number of countries that the list includes, saying it's 2 is not useful in my case as most of the entries are from single country.

What I would want instead is some metric that would give result slightly higher than 1, suggesting there is mostly just 1 country.

In some sense, this is similar to outlier detection. I could use standard deviation but there are two issues,

1. Outlier detection would give a result of 1, while I would prefer a result slightly higher than 1.
2. Most of the times, the number of unique values is going to be less than 10, even as low as 2-3, so the standard deviation will be too high to be useful.